# Ruby 1.9.2 + heroku gem + rails 3 + windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

On my windows computer, I installed Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.3 successfully. I then installed the the heroku gem (gem install heroku), version 1.17.10, and it installed fine. When I tried to run "heroku version", it gave me a message, "This application has failed to start because msvcrt-ruby18.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem."

Can anybody tell me what to do now? I appreciate any help that I can get.

Comment: Did you use the installer from rubyinstaller.org and did you also install the devkit?

Comment: @nathanvda - No I did not. I wasn't aware that I had to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the gems that you have installed has been compiled for Ruby 1.8.x and not Ruby 1.9.x

The binary part (extension) link against the Ruby shared library (DLL) of that version, so `msvcrt-ruby18.dll`

For them to work on Ruby 1.9.x, they need to also include the binary extension that links against to the shared library of Ruby 1.9.x

There are two known gems that present this issue: JSON and win32-api.

This has been discussed on [RubyInstaller group](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller) several times:

[Issues with win32-api (and instructions)](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller/browse_thread/thread/1b86971f58494aaf)

In that link will find also instructions how to solve JSON gem too.

To install the RubyInstaller DevKit, please go to our [downloads page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads) and once you obtain the binary, follow [the instructions in our wiki](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)

Since you haven't provided exact output of the error, I'm doing my best to guess what is the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Luis for stepping in and answering, I knew you would know best.

Comment: Thanks Luis. I downloaded the dev kit and extracted it. How do I know that I have installed it successfully? Do I have to uninstall ruby, rails, and re-install them?

Comment: The RubyInstaller instructions are here: http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Comment: Thanks Luis. The instructions at github did it.  I got "heroku version" to work without the error.